# Using square bracketed numbers as inputs in functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $f(x)=x^2+1$, find $f([-1,2])$.

I am not sure how to find the answer seeing the square brackets. I wrote the answer as $[2,5]$ but I am not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $[-1,2]$ denotes the closed interval $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid -1\leq x\leq2\}$, $f([-1,2])$ is the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in[-1,2]\}$.

In general, for any set $X$, the notation $f(X)$ is used to denote the *image* of the set $X$ under $f$. The image of a function $f$ over a set $X$ is equal to the set of all values $f(x)$ for $x\in X$, or, in notation...

$$f(X)=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$$

If $f$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, then the image $f([a,b])$ can also be written as an interval...
$$f([a,b])=\left[\min\{f([a,b])\},
max\{f([a,b])\}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not coorect. The expression $f\bigl([-1,2]\bigr)$ means $\{f(x)\,|\,x\in[-1,2]\}$, which turns out to be equal to $[1,5]$.

Comment: $(-1)^2=1,1+1=2, f([-1,2])=[2,5]$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It's not correct. Note that $0\in [-1,2]$, so $1=f(0)\in f([-1,2])$, but $1\notin [2,5]$.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but then would f({-1,2}) = {2,5}, similarly?

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Ah, right.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You were right the first time, sorry.

Comment: @R.Burton Yes. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

This notation denotes the image of a set, in this case the image of a closed interval:.
$$f([-1,2]) = \{f(x) : x\in[-1,2]\} = \{f(x) : -1\le x \le 2\}$$
From the contuinity of $f$ follows that the image of an interval is also an interval. Therefore, to find $f([-1,2])$ It is enough to find the minimal and maximal value of $f$ on the interval $[-1,2]$.

Quadratic functions $f(x)=(x-p)^2+q$ have global minimum at $x=p$ with the value $f(p)=q$. In your case you have $p=0$, and $q=1$. $x=0\in[-1,2]$ so $f(0)=1$ will be the minimal value of $f$ on this interval. 
Moreover function $f(x)=x^2+1$ is increasing for $x>0$ and decreasing for $x<0$, so its maximal value will be on one of the end points of the interval. you have $f(2)=5>f(-1)=2$, so the maximal value of $f$ on this interval is $f(2)=5$

The final answer is $f([-1,2])=[1,5]$.